# Where is the eos blockchain downloaded on ubuntu when running the nodeos command?

Tags: nodeos

I finally got eosio installed on ubuntu and ran the command:

```
nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin
```

I see that its syncing with the blockchain, but where is the eos blockchain being downloaded to? Is there a light mode as I only have less than 9gb of free space.

Comment: you're running a test net with one producer so it's not synching to mainnet. you need to provide the `genesis.json` of the net and sone seed peers to connect to